# The Matrix of $T$ Relative to the Ordered Bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, let $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ be different ordered bases for $V$, and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Then Hoffman and Kunze in *Linear Algebra, Second Edition* define (although under more general premises) an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that

$$[T\alpha]_{\mathcal B'}=A[\alpha]_{\mathcal B}$$

as **the matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$**.

Under my premises, would this definition not be ambiguous? For example, it could also refer to an $A$ such that

$$[T\alpha]_{\mathcal B}=A[\alpha]_{\mathcal B'},$$

unless the order in which $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ appear in the **bolded** definition matters, which I assume does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed matter. Let's write $$f:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{W},$$ then choose $\mathcal{B}'=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ as an ordered base of $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{B}=(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ as an ordered base of $\mathcal{W}$ (this statement can be generalized for any finite vector spaces, thus we might have different dimensions).

Then for $v\in\mathcal{V}$ we can write $$v=c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n$$ and because $T$ is linear we get $$f(v)=f(c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n)=c_1f(v_1)+\dots +c_nf(v_n).$$ This implies, that $f$ is entirely determined by $f(v_1),\dots f(v_n)$. With $\mathcal{B}$ we can write $$f(v_j)=a_{1j}w_1+\dots+ a_{mj}w_m.$$ This yields, that $f$ is completely determined by all of the $a_{ij}$. If we put these into a matrix $A$, we finally get $f(v)=Av$.

As we calculated the $a_{ij}$ using the specific bases, this matrix might change if we choose different bases, thus the order is important.

You might also want to check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices), there is a nice visual representation.

Comment: I know $[T\alpha]_{\mathcal B'}=A[\alpha]_{\mathcal B}\not\Longleftrightarrow[T\alpha]_{\mathcal B}=A[\alpha]_{\mathcal B'}$ because neither $[T\alpha]_{\mathcal C}$ nor $[\alpha]_{\mathcal C}$ might even make sense for some $\mathcal C\in\{\mathcal B,\mathcal B'\}$. What I'm concerned about is whether the bolded definition is ambiguous with my restrictions.

Comment: @Josué that's why I adressed the changing of the bases. The coefficents $a_{ij}$ might change if we choose a different basis for $\mathcal{V}$ or $\mathcal{W}$ or both. Thus if we look at an endomorphism $$T:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{V},$$ we can't just change the position of our bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$.

Answer (score 1):

The order of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ in the bolded definition *does* matter, that's why it is unambiguous. Often the matrix $A$ is written as $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}\ $; again, this notation is not ambiguous as the positions of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ are not interchangeable.